# how to declare an empty numeric (number) value in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to create an object with some non-defined values.
I know how to declare an empty string- in example that would be a object.name. But what would be an empty numeric value. What do I need to put instead of word 'number' in object.age property to tell the javaScript it can be any number?

```
let object = {
name : ''
age : number
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "any number"? How can a number be empty?

Comment: Best to use `null` value for just defining the variable, (to not get undefined), and you can easy check is it null with `if (object.age===null) {}`.

Comment: @Ultrazz008, would null refer to any datatype, or just a number ?

Comment: @MarioNezmah It refers to any datatype, but you can put inside whatever you like.

Comment: @MarioNezmah `null` has its own type (but if you ask `typeof`, it pretends to be an object). JavaScript is dynamically typed. `var x = 42; x = "hello"; x = [{}, {}, {}];` is not an error.

Comment: @melpomene, What I meant was: this property has no value yet, but when the value is assigned, it should be a number

Comment: @MarioNezmah Define "should". As I said above, JavaScript doesn't care about types.

Comment: @MarioNezmah JavaScript doesn't care about types, it can be anything (if you defined number, you can just add string instead of number and it will be accepted), but you could make your class, with private variables, and sets, gets and you can do check there does he sets at age number or is trying to push string and you could warn him.

Comment: Use either `0` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), *not a number* as value, this values has a number type and not a usefull value.

```
let object = {
    name : '',
    age : NaN
};
```

If you not like to use `NaN`, you might use [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) or just [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), but the first one is an object and the second is `undefined` as type.

And for checking if value equals to these defines:

```
NaN: isNaN(object.age)
null: object.age===null
undefined: typeof object.age==="undefined"
```

Comment: A good non-usable value for `age`, could be just `-1`.